# Dealing with non-idempotent $http requests in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to model/access data from a non-idempotent request throughout my application.

As an example we'll say I have an API that returns a random author for a user to view.  I need to display info about this author in various places in the app, and then occasionally I need to re-call the `getNext` method to get the next random author, and update all of the bindings in the app.

I have the following factory:

```
.factory('author', function($http) {
    return {
        data: {},
        getNext: function() {
            return $http.get('/path/to/endpoint').then(function(res) {
                angular.copy(res.data, this.data)
                return res;
            }.bind(this));  
    };    
});
```

Then in my controllers I simply bind my data appropriately:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, author) {
    $scope.author = author.data;

    author.getNext();
});
```

And rendered data in my view:

```
<h2>{{author.name}}</h2>
<div ng-repeat="book in author.books">
    {{book.title}} - {{book.year}}
</div>
```

This works, but it feels more than a little hacky to copy a new object into the old one to get updates to trigger.

What's more, I can't access the promise generated by `getNext` in any other controller than the one I originally call it in.  What I would like to do is have `data` be the last `getNext` promise that was called.  Meaning if I call a new `getNext`, `data` becomes the new promise and all of my `.then`s will re-execute when it's loaded.

Maybe `data` needs to be a `$q.defer()` that I then resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have the 'author' service act as the author entity, I would just use it as a DAO.

```
.factory('Author', function($http) {
    function AuthorService(){
        this.getNext = function(){
            return $http.get('/path/to/endpoint').then(function(res) {
                return res.data; 
            })
        } 
    }; 
    return new AuthorService()   
});

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Author) {
      Author.getNext().then(function(author){
         $scope.author = author
      });
});
```